# compare 1 object array to 2nd array compare by key

Tags: ios, arrays

I have 2 arrays.  Array 1 returns different numbers.  Example:(29, 30).  Array 2 has objects.  Example:

```
    ({
        IDCode = 5;
        dateEnd = "04/08/2016";
        dateStart = "04/08/2016";
    },
        {
        IDCode = 30;
        dateEnd = "04/09/2016";
        dateStart = "04/09/2016";
    },
    {
        IDCode = 55;
        dateEnd = "04/10/2016";
        dateStart = "04/10/2016";
    })
```

I would like to compare the first array to the IDCode of the second array.  IF they match I want to make a new array of only the matching numbers. If using the example above i would only return array3

```
    {
        IDCode = 30;
        dateEnd = "04/09/2016";
        dateStart = "04/09/2016";
    }
```

I made a predicate that returned  `IDCode == {"29", "30"}`  But I am getting no matches.

I think i have to create a loop and only test the valueForKey to the second array, but i don't know where to start.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution!! efficient also.

```
NSArray *IDCodeArray = @[@29, @30, @31];
NSArray *dataArray = @[
                       @{
                           @"IDCode" : @5,
                           @"dateEnd" : @"04/08/2016",
                           @"dateStart" : @"04/08/2016"
                       },
                       @{
                           @"IDCode" : @30,
                           @"dateEnd" : @"04/09/2016",
                           @"dateStart" : @"04/09/2016"

                       },
                       @{
                           @"IDCode" : @55,
                           @"dateEnd" : @"04/10/2016",
                           @"dateStart" : @"04/10/2016"
                       },
                       @{
                           @"IDCode" : @29,
                           @"dateEnd" : @"04/11/2016",
                           @"dateStart" : @"04/11/2016"
                        }
                       ];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// loop through each object using fast enumeration

[IDCodeArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *idcode, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    __block NSUInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;

    // loop through data array to find IDcode
    foundIndex = [dataArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary  *dictObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        // stop the loop if found
        NSUInteger IDCodeObject = [dictObject valueForKey:@"IDCode"];
        return (IDCodeObject.integerValue == idcode.integerValue);
    }];

    // add object to result array if found
    if(foundIndex != NSNotFound){
        [resultArray addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:foundIndex]];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"Result Array : %@", resultArray);
```

===================================

To find all matching values including duplicate codes

```
// loop through each object using fast enumeration

[IDCodeArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *idcode, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    // loop through data array to find IDcode

    [dataArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary  *dictObject, NSUInteger index, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        NSUInteger IDCodeObject = [[dictObject valueForKey:@"IDCode"] integerValue];

        if(IDCodeObject == idcode.integerValue){
            [resultArray addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:index]];
        }

    }];

}];
```

Comment: Those ID codes are strings when they should be numbers.

Comment: It does not matter if they strings or number, I am converting them into integer finally

Comment: You are doing that conversion *a lot*.  Does that sound efficient to you?

Comment: @trojanfoe Please check my edited answer. I did conversion to match the exact IDCode value. if its already an integer then it would not be needed.

Comment: Much better, however `IDCodeArray` needs conversion also.

Comment: yes it worked but the only problem is that once it found a matching number it stopped.  I might have more than on idcode 30 and need to add all matching idcodes

Comment: I am not using int, since i am not actually doing any calculations on it, i kept it as strings.

Comment: is there any way to keep going thru the loop till all the numbers in the dataArray have been checked,  since it could have idcode 30, 45, 30, 178, 23, 30.   I need to display all matching which includes the 3 idcodes of 30?

Comment: @RichCarlton Please refer my updated answer. You will get both ways you want either redundant or duplicate(all).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like below line of code. Use **IN**.

```
NSPredicate *intersectPredicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", otherArray];
NSArray *intersect = 
[firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersectPredicate];
```

Reference Link : http://ronnqvi.st/array-intersections-and-differences/

**Update:**

```
 NSPredicate *intersectPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY IDCode IN(%@), otherArray];
 NSArray *result = [your_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersectPredicate];
```

Reference Link : [NSPredicate for Array of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201251/nspredicate-for-array-of-dictionaries)

Comment: That does not work.  I think a predicate can be a word.  A predicate cannot be a array.   So I believe since I am testing if any of the numbers in array 1 match any of the Object for key IDCODE in array 2 must be done in some kind of loop.   Any thoughts?

Comment: I have updated my answer check it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7ffb0875d150> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key IDCode.'

Comment: Try with removing `ANY`.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy use NSMutableSet

```
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: array1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray: array2];
[set1 intersectSet: set2];
NSArray *resultArray = [set1 allObjects];
```

Hope it will help :)

```
 NSArray *arr = @[ @{ @"IDCode" : @"5",
                     @"dateEnd" : @"04/08/2016",
                     @"dateStart" : @"04/08/2016"} ,
                  @{ @"IDCode" : @"30",
                     @"dateEnd" : @"04/09/2016",
                     @"dateStart" : @"04/09/2016"},
                  @{ @"IDCode" : @"55",
                     @"dateEnd" : @"04/10/2016",
                     @"dateStart" : @"04/10/2016"}];
NSArray *ar2 = @[@{ @"IDCode" : @"5",
                    @"dateEnd" : @"04/08/2016",
                    @"dateStart" : @"04/08/2016"}];

NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: arr];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray: ar2];
[set1 intersectSet: set2];
NSArray *resultArray = [set1 allObjects];
```

and it is working for me ......

Comment: Printing description of resultArray:
<__NSArrayI 0x797c5810>(
{
    IDCode = 5;
    dateEnd = "04/08/2016";
    dateStart = "04/08/2016";
}
)