# NSPredicate to filter an Array of Dictionaries (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nspredicate

I'm trying to learn the wonderful world of NSPredicate, but am failing on practical application.  Any guidance is appreciated.

In particular, I want to use NSPredicate to filter an array of Dictionaries.  For example, take the following array and filter it down to just those entries where "species" == "dog".

```
 var arrayofDictionary:[[String:String]] = [

      ["name": "Ben", "species": "human"], 
      ["name": "Harp", "species": "dog"], 
      ["name": "Guinness", "species": "dog"]

 ]
```

Now I know how to filter the following way, but my understanding is this is the "lazy" way to do it and will not run as fast when doing large computations:

```
 let filteredArray = arrayofDictionary.filter { $0["species"] == "dog" }.flatMap { $0 }
```

So I have been playing around with NSPredicate, and feel like the following may be a good starting place, but am not sure how to use it next.  Also, perhaps this only works for an array and not dictionaries?

```
 let speciesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "species == %@", "dog")
```

Thanks for your help!

---

I was only able to find guidance on this in Objective-C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201251/nspredicate-for-array-of-dictionaries).  Unfortunately I only am starting to pick up Swift.

This was [a good tutorial on NSPredicate](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) to start to get my head wrapped around it, but I couldn't figure out how to fully implement for the case mentioned above.

Comment: Where have you heard that using swift closures *"is the "lazy" way to do it and will not run as fast when doing large computations"*? I would ALWAYS go for closures, they are typesafe and not prone to refactoring errors. But I think you can and should drop the `flatMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  What does flatMap do exactly?  Just curious why you recommend to drop it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment by @luk2302, in that using the Swift `Array` `filter` method is nicer in general than filtering with an `NSPredicate`.  If you're worried about performance across a large data set you should have your content in `CoreData` and use an `NSPredicate` as part of an `NSFetchRequest` with proper indexing setup in your data model.

Having said that, filtering by `NSPredicate` is not explicitly supporting with the Swift `Array` type, so you would have to cast to `NSArray` to use it.  It would look something like this:

```
let filteredArray = (arrayofDictionary as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(speciesPredicate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That approached worked perfectly.  Based on your feedback and luk2302 I am going to go with the closure filter.  If I run into performance issues at some point then will revisit NSPredicate.

Answer (score 5):

Please check this out

```
var customerNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"alagu","MiddleName":"prabhu"];
var clientNameDict = ["firstName":"Selva","LastName":"kumar","MiddleName":"m"];
var employeeNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"prabhu","MiddleName":"kp"];


var attributeValue = "karthi";
var arrNames:Array = [customerNameDict,clientNameDict,employeeNameDict];
var namePredicate =NSPredicate(format: "firstName like %@",attributeValue);


let filteredArray = arrNames.filter { namePredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
println("names = ,\(filteredArray)");
```